# How to set zero padding to EVP_CIPHER?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, evp-cipher

Is possible to set [Zero Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Zero_padding) when using EVP_CIPHER.

I know that the default padding for `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` is enabled and it uses PKCS padding.

And with `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding` you can only enable and disable the padding.

Comment: Good question. Grepping the sources, I don't believe you can do it. Maybe someone on the [OpenSSL mailing list](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mailing.openssl.users) could say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wikipedia correctly notes, zero-padding is not standardized for encryption. It may not be deterministic if the plaintext can end with `00` bytes. Furthermore, there are implementations that add an additional block if the plaintext contains an integral number of blocks, others do not add an additional block.

I haven't seen zero-padding in the EVP cipher suite, but it is very simple to implement yourself by simply performing the padding yourself, and  then disabling the padding. One method is  to copying the plaintext to a block of zero values, e.g. created by `memset`. The only problem with the approach is that you cannot simply switch between padding modes, it remains a special case.

If possible, try to use PKCS#7 compatible padding scheme instead. If you have to go with zero padding, make sure you can retrieve the size of the plaintext and define in advance if an additional block of zero's is added or not (PHP, for instance, does not, Bouncy Castle does).